# How to pass array of custom objects to ASMX webservice?

Tags: asmx, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to pass an array of custom objects from my asp.net code behind to a webservice method.  The webservice is ASMX and I can't change that for now.  I can verify up to the point of the code behind calling the webservice, that the custom object is in the array and has the proper values.  When I put a break point in the webservice, I notice that the array is null.

- I have checked my Service Reference and the collection type is System.array.
- I read that I might need to mark my custom class with [DataContract] and the properties as [Datamember] for this to work, but these don't even show up in the intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all kinds of things and I couldn't get this to work.  I tried casting the custom objects as objects and passing them that way.  I also tried to cast the whole array as type object and that didn't work.  I tried collections; no go.  I read a lot on this and couldn't find anyone who could actually do this.  So I gave up on doing this with ASMX and tried it with a WCF service.  That did work nicely.  I created a custom object.  I created a strongly typed collection of this class and populated the collection.  I then passed this collection to the WCF service and the method was able to see all the objects properly.  So if anybody is stuck in the situation I was, try a regular WCF service.

Comment: Please share your code...am stuck in passing array of objects to wcf service using ksoap 2